# GoLang strange error for struct method call

Tags: go, struct, methods

Trying to learn GoLang now and have issue with one of the tasks. Problem is I need to define method Shoot for struct having Ammo and Power fields. However it shoots me instead of imaaginary enemy with following error:
compiler.go:64:20: testStruct.Shoot undefined (type *Hero has no field or method Shoot)
I've checked docs, few tutorials and seems I declared method well. However I getting this error. Here is my code:

````
В рамках этого урока мы постарались представить себе уже привычные нам переменные и функции, как объекты из реальной жизни. Чтобы закрепить результат мы предлагаем вам небольшую творческую задачу.

Вам необходимо реализовать структуру со свойствами-полями On, Ammo и Power, с типами bool, int, int соответственно. У этой структуры должны быть методы: Shoot и RideBike, которые не принимают аргументов, но возвращают значение bool.

Если значение On == false, то оба метода вернут false.

Делать Shoot можно только при наличии Ammo (тогда Ammo уменьшается на единицу, а метод возвращает true), если его нет, то метод вернет false. Метод RideBike работает также, но только зависит от свойства Power.

Чтобы проверить, что вы все сделали правильно, вы должны создать указатель на экземпляр этой структуры с именем testStruct в функции main, в дальнейшем программа проверит результат.

Закрывающая фигурная скобка в конце main() вам не видна, но она есть.

Пакет main объявлять не нужно!

Удачи!

#code tpl:
func main() {

    // testStruct :=
    /*
     * Экземпляр созданной вами структуры необходимо передать в качестве
     * аргумента функции testStruct, которая выполнит проверку соблюдения
     * всех условий задания/

// }
*/


package main
import (
"fmt"
)

type Hero struct {
    On bool
    Ammo, Power int
}
func Shoot(h Hero) bool {
    if !h.On { return false }
    if h.Ammo>0 {
        h.Ammo--
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
func RideBike(h Hero) bool {
    if !h.On { return false }
    if h.Power>0 {
        h.Power--
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
func main() {
    testStruct := new(Hero)
    testStruct.On = true
    testStruct.Ammo = 10
    testStruct.Power = 100
    fmt.Println (testStruct)
    res := testStruct.Shoot()
    fmt.Println (testStruct)
}```
Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you! Sorry for my English -it's bot my bative language. Thank you again!
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got confused between function argument and receiver.
Try this instead on notice the location of Hero in the functions:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Hero struct {
    On          bool
    Ammo, Power int
}

func (h *Hero) Shoot() bool {
    if !h.On {
        return false
    }
    if h.Ammo > 0 {
        h.Ammo--
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
func (h *Hero) RideBike() bool {
    if !h.On {
        return false
    }
    if h.Power > 0 {
        h.Power--
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
func main() {
    testStruct := new(Hero)
    testStruct.On = true
    testStruct.Ammo = 10
    testStruct.Power = 100
    fmt.Println(testStruct)
    res := testStruct.Shoot()
    fmt.Println(res)
    print(testStruct.Ammo)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need implement method for struct, but you implement function with first args struct.
Use `func (h Hero) Shoot() bool` instead of `func Shoot(h Hero) bool`